# class variable gets reset when calling methods in multiple forms

Tags: c#, winforms

**Updated to reflect to my own source**

I'm in process of building my first winform application in c# and I'm trying to figure out the best practice for structuring my classes to work smoothly when I use them in my forms.
I have a couple of examples which I will try to explain the best way i can.

When working with get/set variables in a class, the best practice should be something like this:

JobMove.cs

```
public class JobMove
{
    private List<string> jobNames { get; set; }
    public string Scanner;

    public JobMove()
    {
        this.Scanner = Properties.Settings.Default.Scanner;
    }

    public void ListSelected(ListBox lbx)
    {
        foreach (string jName in this.jobNames)
        {
            lbx.Items.Add(jName);
        }
    }

    public static List<string> GetCheckedJobs(ListView lw)
    {
        int countChecked = lw.CheckedItems.Count;
        int itemCount = 0;
        List<string> jList = new List<string>();

        foreach (ListViewItem item in lw.CheckedItems)
        {
            JobInfo jobInfo = Job.Find(Convert.ToInt32(lw.Items[item.Index].SubItems[1].Text));
            jList.Add(jobInfo.Name);
            itemCount++;
        }
        return jList;
    }
}
```

My problem is when I combine this with my forms and I call this, then I would try to do something like this:

MyForm1.cs

```
public partial class MyForm1 : Form
{
    private void btnMoveJobs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Scanner = cbxScanners.SelectedItem.ToString();

        JobMove moveJobs = new JobMove();

        frmMoveJobs FrmMoveJobs = new frmMoveJobs();
        FrmMoveJobs.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

MyForm2.cs

```
public partial class frmMoveJobs : Form
{
    public frmMoveJobs()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        JobMove moveJobs = new JobMove();
        lblFrom.Text = moveJobs.Scanner;
        moveJobs.ListSelected(lbxJobsToMove);

        cbxMjScanners.DataSource = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Scanners));
    }
}
```

But when I call *MyClass* in *MyForm2* and I want to call the *DoSomethingElse* method, then myString will be reset to a *null* value. And that makes sense to me, but how do I work around this?

I tried to figure out what to use here to get easier around these flaws in my code, but my knowledge is far too weak to just implement an easy solution.
I know I could just store this variable in Settings.settings as an example, but to me that just seems like a real overload for such a simple task.

I might just need a point in the right direction to right on what to do in this situation.

Comment: That's because you creating a new instance of the class...

Comment: You should really consider moving the `MessageBox.Show` out of `MyClass`. A message box is a UI function, the class should not be concerned with such things. Let the UI layer (forms, etc.) handle UI things (message boxes, labels, etc.).

Comment: Austin: I figured that out too, also wrote that in my post, I'm just looking for a workaround. Anthony: This isn't my real source, this was just an example to hightlight my problem. But maybe I should post some of my own source, to clarify things alittle bit more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do a `MyClass myClass = new MyClass();` then indeed - the values are independent and unrelated. If you want to share the `MyClass` instance then *pass* the `MyClass` instance between the forms. Perhaps:

```
using(var form2 = new Form2()) {
    form2.SensibleName = existingMyClassInstance;
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

(note the `using` above btw; when using `ShowDialog()` it is your job to make sure the form is disposed; it only gets disposed automatically if using `Show()`)

Comment: Since i updated my source above, is this still the right solution? And is this the Best practice when parsing properties between forms in general?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, they're properties, not variables (the variables are the underlying data source).

Secondly, the whole point of `get`/`set` accessors is so you can get and set the value without needing helper methods.

Thirdly, and as to your problem, you're creating a new instance of the class in each form (hinted at by the `new` keyword) and the value of the property will be whatever it is initialised as on construction of the instance (or not.) i.e. the values of properties are not shared between different instances of the same type.

Think of the mold for a key: I can get multiple instances of the key cut from a "blueprint", but any damage that one suffers won't be reflected by the rest - they're unique in that sense.

If you want the forms to both access the same instance of that type, then you will need to stash the instance somewhere in your code which is accessible to both.

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

1. Pass in an instance of `MyClass` in the form2's constructor.
2. Make `MyClass` a static property of either `Form1` or `Form2` and access it via that on the other form.
3. Make `MyClass` static **(not recommended)**.

Comment: (shudders at the `static`, which should very rarely be used for this type of scenario, IMO)

Comment: Noted. Left in as it is still an option, even if ill-advised.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the instance of `MyClass` created in `MyForm1` inside of `MyForm2`, you need to provide it to `MyForm2`.

Something like this would work:

```
public partial class MyForm2 : Form
{
    public MyForm2(MyClass given)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        given.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because each of your form has a new object of "MyClass".

To achieve what you want to do use a static property... this won't be initialized and gives back the same value for each object of MyClass
it looks like this

```
public class MyClass {
   public static string myString { get; set; }

   public void ChangeMyString(string newString)
   {
       myString = newString;
   }

   public void DoSomethingElse()
   {
       MessageBox.Show(myString);
   }

}
```

Comment: a static `myString` with an instance quasi-accessor, and use of `this.myString`.... lots of things that just won't work there, and wouldn't be good ideas even if they did

Answer (score 0):

Easy Solution:

```
private static string myString { get; set; }
```

Why: because you initialize the class again when initializing Form2 and it will create a new class. With the "static" keyword you create a property which is the same in all instances of this class.

**BUT**: please read some books before continuing, this would be the solution to this problem, but the source of many others. Try to understand C# and Forms first, than (or alongside with reading/learning) start coding!